# Issues while getting Puppet custom fact

Tags: puppet

I created a simple custom fact:

```
Facter.add(:hello) do
  setcode do
    "Hello, world"
  end
end
```

and put it here (on puppetmaster):

```
/etc/puppet/modules/custom/lib/facter
```

I'm testing it on puppet client:

```
facter hello
```

and see nothing.

Whereas this command works (on puppet client):

```
facter --puppet hello
Hello, world
```

Checking if the fact is synced (on puppet client):

```
puppetd --test --pluginsync
info: Retrieving plugin
info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/hello.rb
info: Caching catalog for host.example.com
```

It looks like the custom fact is synced fine. I can't understand why it's not available via `facter`.

Also, how can I use this new fact from puppetmaster? I need to build a simple conditional based on the custom fact.

For example, I added in `site.pp` (on puppetmaster):

```
$string = "$hello"
notice("Testing custom fact: $string")
```

Again, in syslog there is no line from the `notice` function.

I studied a lot of documentation and still can't get how to make it work.
I will appreciate if someone could look on this issue.

Thank you.

Configuration: Ubuntu Server 12.04, Puppet 2.7.11, facter 1.6.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom facts from puppet are only used in puppet runs or when you use the `--puppet` flag on `facter`.  If you're not ok with that, then put the custom facts somewhere that facter will always use - see [here](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/custom_facts.html#loading-custom-facts) for details.

The fact should be present for the catalog compile; you probably aren't logging notice messages.  To use it as a condition:

```
if $hello == "Hello, world" {
  notify { "found": }
}
```